# Do blind people learn Braille equally fast as the sighted?

Tags: vision, sensation, learning, language, neuroplasticity

The visually deprived brain undergoes extensive remodeling due to cross-modal plasticity. This leads to increased areas of the cortex being available for other purposes such as tactile processing. Now I am wondering if there is anything known about how long it takes for the blind to learn Braille as compared to normally sighted people?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had a very difficult time finding information that was well-written and what you were looking for. So, I did my best!

From what I have read it takes about four months - everyone is a little bit different and some take longer! Those of us with no visual impairment that try to learn it have no advantage and maybe a slight disadvantage with learning it... I know because I am trying to learn it. It does take a lot a patience and perseverance!

This is the article I referred to: 
[Learning braille; how long does it take and does it get harder with age?](http://www.quora.com/How-long-does-it-take-to-learn-Braille-and-does-it-get-harder-as-you-get-older/)

Hope this was helpful!